# Using OTG cables when connecting to PC

Tags: usb-on-the-go

Can an OTG cable, micro B male to USB A female, be used with the cell phone if connecting to a PC either with a USB A Male to Male lead or with a standard A Male to Female lead plus a standard A Femal to Female adapter?

Comment: This really isn't an Android question.

Answer (score 0):

no, the OTG marks to the phone it's OTG and not normal cable

the easy way is just to use a normal cable